# I cant get any data when i add this query $email=$_POST['RegistrationForm[usernam] in php mailer

Tags: php, html

actually, my html form have name=RegistrationForm[username] in username field if I am changing my name to simple "username" and also change the name in php mailer then working fine. But when I am gonna test with brackets then it doesnot work.

Code :

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$result ="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email=$_POST['RegistrationForm[username]'];  // Get subject
    $pass=$_POST['RegistrationForm[password]'];  // Get Email Value
    ^ error is here in declaration
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `input` field name as `RegistrationForm[username]` then it is considered as an array. And to server it is posting as a 2D array. 
You `$_POST` data would be look like this

```
Array
(
    [RegistrationForm] => Array
    (
        [username] => test
    ),
    .....
)
```

To access your data you can try the following way:

```
$email = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['username'];
$pass = $_POST['RegistrationForm']['password'];
```